# Position view below another view in CoordinatorLayout in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want use `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` , `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` , `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout` in my xml file. What are the possibilities to position a view below another view?

for example : position `ScrollView` beneath `ImageView` in `CoordinatorLayout`.

my xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    tools:context="com.tellfa.smsbox.activities.postShow_Page">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/post_show_coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/post_show_collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/post_picture_image"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/cover_menu_bg2"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/post_show_app_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/post_show_fav_image"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:alpha="0.7"
                        android:src="@drawable/favorite_post_un" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/post_show_share_image"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:alpha="0.7"
                        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/post_show_report_image"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:alpha="0.7"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/post_report" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/post_show_space"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/post_picture_image"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/post_text_layout"
                    style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/category_text">

                        <com.tellfa.smsbox.components.tellfa_TextView_en
                            android:id="@+id/post_text_text"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:text="@string/connect_info"
                            android:textColor="@color/top_user_bg"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </ScrollView>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to set `ScrollView` below in `ImageView`?  TNX <3

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I assume you are trying to position views inside of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. The `CollapsingToolbarLayout` extends `FrameLayout`, so the only possibility is to position views is to utilize view margin and gravity. In your case you could position a `ImageView` like:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp" <-height of the ScrollView
/>
```

If you are trying to add the new `ImageView` directly to the `CoordinatorLayout` you can utilize a [anchor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.html#setAnchorId(int)):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/post_text_layout" <-view to anchor the imageview
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom" <- specifies edge of the anchor that should be used
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" <- how to position this view relatively to the anchoring position
/>
```

Comment: how to position one view to the right of other view?

Comment: @blackHawk change "bottom" to right