# Android Coordinator Layout bottom bar hide inside the list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

The bottom button/some view hides the list view bottom part.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

         <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:context="example.design.activities.DetailsActivity"
                android:background="@color/grey">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:paddingTop="80dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="bottom">

                <!-- Add to cart button -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/ssssss"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="ADD TO CART"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

I will make the bottom view visible and invisible based on condition.

How can I adjust my list view to scroll more if the bottom bar is visible ?

Comment: can you describe more

Comment: I have list of menu items, once user selected the items I will mark a button visible. The image shows the visible button. At this time last element of the list view is hidden behind the button. I want to make it on top/scroll more.

Comment: have you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668144/position-view-below-another-view-in-coordinatorlayout-in-android).

Comment: Yes I have added app:layout_anchor="@+id/post_text_layout" and app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom" . still hiding. scroll view is outside appbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `android:clipToPadding = "false"` in your NestedScrollView.
And when you are showing your bottom button you can dynamically add bottom padding for NestedScrollview with value equals to height of your bottom button.

```
nestedScrollView.setPadding(yourPadding, yourPadding,yourPadding, btn.getMeasuredHeight())
```

Comment: hi getMeasuredHeight returns 0 ?

Comment: only the issue is getting the height. rest is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve your problem,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/ssssss"/>

            <!-- Add to cart button -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/ssssss"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="ADD TO CART"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"

                android:visibility="visible" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>




</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

here is the sample output
[image]

NOTE: 
you have added `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and so you need `android:paddingTop="80dp"` in your recycler view.Instead you can follow as in my solution just give `android:fillViewport="true"` to nestedScrollView and no padding needed for recyclerview.
I hope this solves your issue

Comment: this one will go under the list

Comment: which one bottom view? nope since both are inside a relative layout

Comment: yes i tried it . it is not going under the list . it is below the list the only.You can just go ahead and try :)

Comment: @RoshanA i have attached the sample output as you can see this one is not going under the list

Comment: I have added exactly like this. but going below the last item. What could be ? should be on the bottom of the screen always.

Comment: ohh going below means, is last item is show above this "add to cart" ,overlapping it ? or last item and next this "add to cart"?

Comment: o u understood incorrectly. the bottom  button should be always bottom of the screen and list view should be scroll up

Comment: ya the code behaves like that only . may be you missed something ..
did you include `  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` inside AppCompatButton??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156147/discussion-between-velmurugan-v-and-roshan-a).

Answer (score 0):

You should change NestedScrollView by using layout_anchor as below.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="example.design.activities.DetailsActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/relative_view"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:paddingTop="80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

It put scrollview on top of your bottom bar as per your aspect.

Comment: if add this the top collapse toolbar view giving flickering effect. after scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#EAEAEA"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="example.design.activities.DetailsActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!-- Add to cart button -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/ssssss"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="ADD TO CART"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/ssssss"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingTop="80dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```