# View not being to front on CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, bringtofront

I have a layout which works fine. One view is in front, another in the back.
I'm using CoordinatorLayour because I'm using a FAB.
The front view is a map and the back view is a view showing data when the FAB button is clicked.

For this I've seen those links on SO:

[BringToFront doesn't work inside a coordinator layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469596/bringtofront-doesnt-work-inside-a-coordinator-layout)

[Position view below another view in CoordinatorLayout in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668144/position-view-below-another-view-in-coordinatorlayout-in-android)

[Placing/Overlapping(z-index) a view above another view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android)

Based on the answers I did a simple code. But the front view insists to be in front. Is there something I missing?:

```java
    final RelativeLayout rev = findViewById(R.id.bg_detail);
        final RelativeLayout orange_map = findViewById(R.id.orange_map);
        floatingActionButtonEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                rev.bringToFront();
                rev.getParent().requestLayout();
                rev.invalidate();
            }
        });
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true""
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_base"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/orange_map"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
        <!--fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" /-->
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bg_detail">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:id="@+id/dummy"/>
                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
                        ...
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/floatingactionbutton_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_assignment_white_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/dummy"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the current behavior and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: @azizbekian to bring background view which contains data to front. Just like that

Answer (score 0):

The Android documentation for View#bringToFront says:

> Change the view's z order in the tree, so it's on top of other sibling
>   views. This ordering change may affect layout, if the parent container
>   uses an order-dependent layout scheme (e.g., LinearLayout). Prior to
>   KITKAT this method should be followed by calls to requestLayout() and
>   invalidate() on the view's parent to force the parent to redraw with
>   the new child ordering.

Meaning, you wanna do:

```
rev.bringToFront();
rev.getParent().requestLayout();
rev.getParent().invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I just need to substitute LinearLayout to FrameLayout. After that I changed visibility of inner RelativeLayout to invisible and when I click a button it shows the hidden layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_base"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/orange_map"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>
                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:background="@android:color/white">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                        ...
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingactionbutton_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_assignment_white_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/dummy"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem with the `RelativeLayout` with id `orange_map`. It is covering the whole screen. If you don't want it to visible when you click on the FAB, try to hide it using

`orange_map.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

If you want it to visible, try to change its height to `wrap_content` using

```
orange_map.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

in this case `RelativeLayout` with id `bg_detail` shown up.

Comment: The map, which is currently orange for test purposes must always be in the background. Seems if I change to WRAP_CONTENT it shrinks.